# How to find the column name of maximum value in a row of table in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi i want to find the column name of max vaue of a row in a table

```
ID       col1  col2  col3
1        15     12    10
2        6      10    3
3        25     50    100
4        150    80    90
```

Above is my table structure what i need is to find the max value of each row and then find the column name of that max value
eg  In first row max value is 15 now i want to find that  max value of first row is 15 and at the same time i want to find the column name of that max value 15 is col1(15 =>col1)

**I need result like below one**

```
ID       Maxval   colname
1        15       col1
2        10       col2    
3        100      col3    
4        150      col1
```

After finding the max value and column name i have to insert into another temporary table in the format which is mention above

```
SELECT ID,
(SELECT MAX(LastUpdateDate)
  FROM (VALUES (col1,col2,col3)) AS UpdateDate(LastUpdateDate)) 
 AS LastUpdateDate
FROM TestTable
```

This is the sql query i used to find out the max value of each row in a table but i donno how to find the column name of max value in each row after that only i can able to insert into temp table. Please any one understand my issue and help me to resolve this .Thanks

Comment: Can you use C# or it must be in T-SQL (Olga Romantsova solution probably will work on SQL Server 2012)

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, you can use `apply`:

```
select t.*, v.*
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) v.*
      from (values ('col1', col1), ('col2', col2), ('col3', col3)) v(colname, val)
      order by val desc
     ) v
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `IIF fuinction`. The `IIF() function` returns a value if a condition is TRUE, or another value if a condition is FALSE:

```
    select ID, 
IIF(col1>col2 and col1>col3,col1,IIF(col2>col1 and col2>col3,col2,col3))max_val,
IIF(col1>col2 and col1>col3,'col1',IIF(col2>col1 and col2>col3,'col2','col3'))col_nam
      from TestTable
```

Comment: This works, but it is hard to read and debug with just 3 columns IMHO; what if there are 7 or 15 or 28 columns?

Comment: Well, show the code for choosing the max of 7 columns. :-) I bet adapting the cross apply version is a lot less complex and more scalable than 7 nested sets of IIFs. And time how long it takes you to get it working, whereas adding `,('col3', col3), ('col4', col4), ('col5', col5), ('col6', col6), ('col7', col7)` takes no time at all and is far less error-prone. But YMMV.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, as you can see, I don't indicate that it is universal variant for all cases...but it's good if you haven't got many columns))

Comment: Of course. I'm just suggesting that a good answer solves the immediate problem, a better answer is easy to adapt to predictable expansions of the problem (not every reader who wants to tackle this problem, including this OP later when their schema changes, will have exactly three columns).

Comment: On the other hand,  in cases where you don't have many columns , this can be better. And also it can be used(on condition replacing operator IIF  with CASE or something similar  ) in other databases where you can't use cross/outer apply.